# String index out of range, string input from File

Tags: java

Okay SO. I've got a try-catch block that has no issues but the thing is when I import the first line of a text file, it says that the String index is out of range:33.

That line is "The Dentist Pulled My Tooth Out"
What I'm doing is using a for loop to evaluate every character in a line until we reach the end of said line. If the character is a vowel, then I increment a vowel integer. Otherwise, if it is a blank space, then I change the blank space to a tilde(~). What I want to know is why it says my String is out of range and how would I change a blank space in the line of text from the file to a tilde. I can figure out outputting it to a different file(that's what I have to do) by myself. I'm just confused why its saying its out of range. I've pasted my entire program below.

The goal of the program is to evaluate a text file, character by character, and count the number of vowels. Also, I have to change any blank spaces to tildes, then reoutput to a different text file.

The code is below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Vowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile;
        File dentist = new File("poetry.txt");
        int vowels = 0;

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
                inFile = new Scanner(new File("poetry.txt"));
                String str1 = inFile.nextLine();
                for (int a = 0; a >= 0; a++) {

                    String start;
                    start = str1.substring(a, a + 1);

                    if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("a") == true)
                        vowels++;
                    else if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("e") == true)
                        vowels++;
                    else if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("i") == true)
                        vowels++;
                    else if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("o") == true)
                        vowels++;
                    else if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("u") == true)
                        vowels++;
                    else if (start.equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
                        start = " ";

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this to spot the problem?

Comment: You are opening the file within a for loop... I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: As a hint, you might want to consider what conditions you are using to end the for loops.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i>=0; i++){` Your loop will never start. The starting is 0 and you condition is that if `i > or if i == 0.`

Comment: @peeskillet the loop starts, but looks it will never finish.

Comment: @peeskillet Wouldn't it rather never end?

Comment: Don't blame peeskillet... it's weird and I misread it too at first. :)

Comment: @sdanzig not blaming him/her, just trying to help to read the code one more time.

Comment: As the `i` is never used inside the loop, the `for` statement boils down to `for(;;)`.

Comment: sorry guys, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on in this piece of code.

```
for(int i = 0; i>=0; i++){
inFile = new Scanner(new File("poetry.txt")); 
String str1 = inFile.nextLine();
```

1. That will loop almost 2^32/2 - 1 times.
2. That creates a new Scanner object everytime.
3. You are reading the first time everytime.

   ```
   for(int a = 0; a >= 0; a++) {
       String start; 
       start = str1.substring(a, a + 1); 
   }
   ```
4. This will again loop for 2^32/2 - 1 times.

   Since the str1 is not as big as the variable 'a' can be, it crashes. You need to make this loop as

   ```
   for(int a = 0; a < (str1.length() - 1); a++) {
       String start = str1.substring(a, a + 1);
   }
   ```

This should sorta fix your problem.

Comment: I did what you said - but the one thing thats missing is when it exits. For some reason, i think a is infinitely incrementing and has no limit because something is wrong with the str1 string. I printed out the first line of the text file and it is correct, its just that I don't think that its moving on the next character. I think its either stuck there or doesn't recognize the limits of str1.length() @lead_the_zeppelin

Answer (score 2):

You should take the `new Scanner` out of the loop, then change your loop to `while(inFile.hasNextLine())` ... you're not using "i" at all.

Also, your inner loop will never end, and that's why you're getting an index exception.  Instead of having `a>=0`, replace that with `a<str1.length()`.

Replace that substring thing with `str1.charAt(a)`, then compare that char (not String) to single quoted chars... 'a', 'e', 'i', etc. using a simple ==.  char is a native datatype, so you can just do `Character.toLowerCase(start) == 'a'`  Notice I forced the character to lowercase before comparing, which replaces the "ignore case".  You don't have to do the `Character.toLowerCase` every time if you just say `start = Character.toLowerCase(start)` though.

Comment: Those are good advises but do not explain the source of the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Added mention about the actual error you were getting.  Making a substring and trying to access "a+1" is setting you up for problems and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do away the long if-else structure by using

```
String STR_VOWELS = "aeiou";
if(STR_VOWELS.contains(start)) {
    vowels++;
} else if (start.equals(" ")) {
    // you can remove this else as well, as you are not doing any thing different here.
    start = " "; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing second for loop with following code, this shall fix your problem

```
 String str1 = inFile.nextLine(); 
          for(int a = 0; a < str1.length()-1; a++){ // a< string.length() otherwise   exception will occur
```

Comment: I took your suggestion....although what's happening now(I placed a SOP statement before the if statement to see what was going on) is that there is an infinite loop going on...maybe it's because when I'm trying to compare the letters I never told it when to stop... @Dark Knight

Comment: It should be `a < str1.length() - 1`.

Comment: still running an infinite for loop - read above - i think its because I never told it when to stop...it should be stopping at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

For replace blank,
When you get the input in to a one string then simply use

```
String my_new_str = my_str.replaceAll(" ", "~");
```

then write back to a file

[String replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)